# Publishing a Webgl project from a specific scene on unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, game-development

I am currently new to Unity and I used the Lego microgame tutorial to see how to use Unity. I also did this tutorial about making a menu (https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/lego-mod-customize-menus?projectId=5f3cfedbedbc2a002093abe3#5f807447edbc2a231ea07d1a).

I did that and publish with Webgl from the software and it only publish the game first without the menu.

How can I do to fix this? I've searched on google and I didnt find anything :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly, You are publish the game without menu. It should be because you have not set the sequence of scene. You can set it on build setting
[setting on this area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exYLe.png)

If i guess correctly, the `menu scene` should be below the `game scene`. The only step you need to do `menu scene` move it above A `game scene` And then public you game again. It's because Unity will load the top scene of build setting on game starting.

If you don't know how to find build setting, Go to File > Build Settings.